# MathJax does not allow multi-row in-line math on GitHub Pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, equation, mathjax

This is my `mathjax.html`:

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {
      equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "all" },
      tagSide: "right"
    },
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    }
  });
</script>
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mathjax/MathJax@legacy-v2-develop/unpacked/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
</script>
```

It is being included in `head.html` in the `_includes\` folder

```html
% include mathjax.html %
```

It works very well on my GitHub Page. However, it does not allow for multiple rows in in-line math objects. For example,

```latex
Let $X = \left[ \begin{matrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \end{matrix} \right]$ follow a [bivariate normal distribution](/D/bvn):
```

incorrectly gives

[image: incorrect, but desired notation]

such that I have to use the undesired notation

```latex
Let $X = \left[ \begin{matrix} X_1 & X_2 \end{matrix} \right]^\mathrm{T}$ follow a [bivariate normal distribution](/D/bvn):
```

which correctly leads to

[image: correct, but undesired notation]

Is there a way to include multiple rows in in-line math. (In stand-alone equations, i.e. with `$$ ... $$`, it works!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not that MathJax doesn't support line breaks in in-line math (it does), but rather the issue is probably an interaction with the Markdown engine with the mathematical notation, and in particular, with the `\\`, as explained below.

In Markdown, the backslash (`\`) is an escape character that can be used to prevent the action of a character that would normally be interpreted by Markdown as having a special meaning.  For example, the `[` in `[bivariate normal distribution](/D/bvn)` is a special character that indicates a link, but if you used `\[bivariate normal distribution](/D/bvn)`, that would produce a literal `[` rather than a link, as in "[bivariate normal distribution](/D/bvn)" (with the `\` removed`).

Now `\` only has this special meaning when the character following it is one that has an action in Markdown, so `\begin`, for example, will keep the `\`, whereas in `\\`, since `\` has a special meaning, the first one escapes the second one, producing just `\` in the HTML page. That makes your expression become

```latex
$X = \left[ \begin{matrix} X_1 \ X_2 \end{matrix} \right]$
```

in the resulting HTML page, and so you no longer have the row terminator `\\` but rather the spacing command `\`  (which is why there is a space between the two X's).  If you use the MathJax contextual menu to show the math as TeX code, you can check if it is `\\` or just `\`.  Or you can view the page source and check it that way.

One possible solution would be to use `\\\\` instead of `\\`, as that will generate two literal backslashes in Markdown.

Alternatively, you might consider using `\atop` rather than the `matrix` environment:

```latex
$X = \left[ X_1 \atop X_2 \right]$
```

This will use less vertical space, and will avoid the `\\` issue in Markdown.

Comment: Dear @DavideCervone, thanks for the comprehensive response! The strategy using escape characters, i.e. `\\\\`, does indeed work and I would recommend this as the simplest as well as Markdownest solution. Many thanks also for your clarifications regarding possible misconceptions with MathJax.