# Mathjax does not render pmatrix correctly on github

Tags: github, markdown, mathjax

I'm using the following code in some markdown:

```
$$
PE_{\text{input}} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\sin\left(\frac{1}{10000^0}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{1}{10000^{0.5}}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{1}{10000^2}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{1}{10000^{2.5}}\right) \\
\sin\left(\frac{2}{10000^0}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{2}{10000^{0.5}}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{2}{10000^2}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{2}{10000^{2.5}}\right)
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0.8415 & 0.99995 & 0.0001 & 1 \\
0.9093 & 0.9998 & 0.0002 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
```

It renders correctly in markdown all in one and when I put it through a syntax checker I can't find anything wrong. In Markdown All in One Preview:

[image]

However it causes markdown all in ones' TOC feature to break and it renders like this on GitHub:

[image]

I haven't been able to isolate what is wrong with it. I've tried removing left / right, separating the two matrices, and messing around with the string but the result is always the same.

Online syntax check:

[image]

### Trying to Escape Backslashes

Trying to use the technique [shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77333242/mathjax-does-not-allow-multi-row-in-line-math-on-github-pages)

```
$$
PE_{\text{input}} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\\\
\sin\left(\frac{1}{10000^0}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{1}{10000^{0.5}}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{1}{10000^2}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{1}{10000^{2.5}}\right) \\\\
\sin\left(\frac{2}{10000^0}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{2}{10000^{0.5}}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{2}{10000^2}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{2}{10000^{2.5}}\right)
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\\\
0.8415 & 0.99995 & 0.0001 & 1 \\\\
0.9093 & 0.9998 & 0.0002 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
```

The output remains the same when trying this.

Comment: This is the same issues as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77333242/mathjax-does-not-allow-multi-row-in-line-math-on-github-pages/77338223#77338223) see my answer there.  Note that the `\\` in your original have been turned into `\` in the HTML page but  he Markdown processing.  You can use `\\\\` instead to overcome that problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MathJax does not allow multi-row in-line math on GitHub Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77333242/mathjax-does-not-allow-multi-row-in-line-math-on-github-pages)

Comment: @DavideCervone - negative. I just give the backslash trick a go and the results are the same. I replaced all instances of \\ with \\\\

Comment: @DavideCervone I couldn't get the multiline with double escape to work but you did get me going in the right direction. See my answer below for what I had to do to make it work.

Comment: @DavideCervone you may find the update in the answer interesting. It also seems to have something to do with what additional commands proceed the pmatrix command.

Answer (score 1):

This is what finally worked for me. I updated the code so that it all fit on one line and used three \ (\) to generate the matrix:

```
$$ PE_{\text{input}} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\\ \sin\left(\frac{1}{10000^0}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{1}{10000^{0.5}}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{1}{10000^2}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{1}{10000^{2.5}}\right) \\\ \sin\left(\frac{2}{10000^0}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{2}{10000^{0.5}}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{2}{10000^2}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{2}{10000^{2.5}}\right) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\\ 0.8415 & 0.99995 & 0.0001 & 1 \\\ 0.9093 & 0.9998 & 0.0002 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
```

@DavideCervone is right - it is definitely something with the \s but I wasn't able to fix it by escaping them on the multiline version.

### Update

I have also noticed that this works IF it comes first.

```
$$
W_O = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0.37738326 & 0.83274845 & 0.37280978 & 0.14584743 \\\\
0.28706851 & 0.29072609 & 0.69116998 & 0.20106682 \\\\
0.26764653 & 0.12058646 & 0.82634382 & 0.60818759 \\\\
0.44329703 & 0.4425581  & 0.89811744 & 0.24551412 \\\\
0.9186323  & 0.40029736 & 0.17636762 & 0.06896409 \\\\
0.41921272 & 0.0495383  & 0.77792527 & 0.4354529  \\\\
0.14791365 & 0.66822966 & 0.48313699 & 0.94127396 \\\\
0.11604641 & 0.51794357 & 0.62942357 & 0.76420883
\end{pmatrix}
$$
```

but then this code that follows it does not.

```
$$
\text{Concat}(\text{Attention}_1, \text{Attention}_2)\times W_{O}=
\text{MultiHead}(Q,K,V)=
\begin{pmatrix}
4.42554033 & 5.589241 & 6.99844643 & 4.79288192 \\\\
4.55176485 & 5.6122494 & 7.09923364 & 4.82144704 \\\\
4.21254506 & 5.31988824 & 6.84520426 & 4.79017392
\end{pmatrix}
$$
```

Making them both one line fixes it.

So there also appears to be some interaction with the additional commands.

Comment: Are there any spaces at the ends of any of the lines?  Markdown uses two spaces to indicate a forced line break, and that could cause the problem.  Also, the second has multiple underscores, which Markdown uses as delimiters for italics, and that will insert `<emph>` or similar tags into the math, making MathJax ignore it.  Look at the page source from the browser and see if there are any HTML tags in the middle of the math.